# C Program to Print an Integer (Entered by the User) Wrong Output Coming When The number is BIG

Tags: c

Here is my code for the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int number;

   printf("Enter an integer: ");

   scanf("%d", &number);

   printf("You entered: %d", number);
   return 0;
}
```

If I enter an integer: `12345678912345678`
Result is Showing: `1578423886`

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Different variable types have min and max values. The number you're entering is bigger than an `int`'s max value.

Comment: `12345678912345678` is a 54-bit number.  In hex it's `0x2bdc545e14d64e`.  Interestingly enough `1578423886` is `0x5e14d64e`.

Comment: Neither the answer in the linked duplicate nor the ones here are fully correct because it is "undefined behaviour" as described in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 section 7.21.6.2 paragraph 10. Everything can happen, it might even kill your cat. That's why you must **always** check the return of `scanf`!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the system you're running on, `int` is not large enough to store integers as large as you're trying to enter (the limit is architecture-specific, and can be checked via `INT_MAX`). If you define your variable as a `long long` instead, it will be able to hold larger values (`long long` is 64 bits on most common architectures), and so:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    long long number;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%lld", &number);

    printf("You entered: %lld", number);
    return 0; 
}
```

outputs:

```
Enter an integer: 12345678912345678
You entered: 12345678912345678
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because data types on any  programming language have limits, so you cannot simply put any number into an integer data type. Probably for your test the limit is 2.147.483.647 for integer data type, if you want to receive a bigger number you will have to switch to long or maybe unsigned long, it all depends of your needs, and when it comes to handle really really big numbers probably you will need to read it as string and then parse it to a special structure or class than can handle that really big number.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because On a system if the value won't fit in an `int`, then the result of the conversion is implementation-defined. (Or, starting in C99, it can raise an implementation-defined signal, but I don't know of any compilers that actually do that.) What *typically* happens is that the **high-order bits are discarded**, but you shouldn't depend on that. (The rules are different for unsigned types; the result of converting a signed or unsigned integer to an unsigned type is well defined.)

Because of this discarding you get result like mention in comment `12345678912345678 is a 54-bit number. In hex it's 0x2bdc545e14d64e. Interestingly enough 1578423886 is 0x5e14d64e`(lower bits are same and higher are discarded)